# How to check if user has Admin rights

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if there's a proper way to check with Powershell if a user has Administrator privileges?

The problem is that we don't have people added to the Local Admin Group. When a user is Admin it's enrolled in Intune 'Device Admin'.

So what I was thinking is to check if a user can do RunAs but I don't wat to get the prompt.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ralph

Comment: On Windows, a simple check is the following, though I don't know if it'll work in your scenario: `$isAdmin = $(net session *>$null; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AzureAD Device Administrator role is added to the local Administrators group, not individual Device Admins, so you can't check for membership of a local group. Instead, try checking whether their UPN has the Global or Device Administrators roles. A quick and untested example (implementing auth might be difficult):

```
$admins = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {
    'Device Administrator','Global Administrator' -contains $_.displayName
} | Foreach-Object {
    Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $_.ObjectId
}

$isAdmin = $admins | Foreach-Object {
    Get-AzureADUser | If($_.UserPrincipalName -eq ((whoami.exe /UPN) | Out-String)) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Alternatively as mklement0 mentioned, `net session *>$null; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` will check if the current PowerShell session is elevated, but not if the user themselves is an admin.